# Why is irc sending "command uknown"?

Tags: c++, sockets, bots, irc

I am trying to write an irc bot in c++ and have taken care of connecting and setting my nickname as well as the identity, pings are functioning also. The only problem I'm having is joining a channel. The server keeps sending back "JOIN :unknown command" I believe the following lines are most relevant:

```
#define JOIN "JOIN #test\r\n"
send(IrcSocket, JOIN, strlen(JOIN),0);
```

on the off chance that nothing can be solved from what I have included the entrie program which might be a bit of an eyesore.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iresult=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
    if(iresult!=0)
    {
                  printf("WSAStartup Failed: %d \n", iresult);
                  return 1;
    }
    struct addrinfo *result=NULL, *ptr=NULL, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;
    #define DEFAULT_PORT "6667"
    #define DEFAULT_IP "192.168.0.10"
    iresult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_IP,DEFAULT_PORT,&hints,&result);
    if(iresult!=0)
    {
                  printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iresult);
                  WSACleanup();
                  return 1;
    }
    SOCKET IrcSocket= INVALID_SOCKET;
    ptr=result;
    IrcSocket=socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (IrcSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
       printf("Error at socket(): %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
       freeaddrinfo(result);
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
    }
    iresult=connect(IrcSocket,ptr->ai_addr,ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if(iresult==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       closesocket(IrcSocket);
       IrcSocket=INVALID_SOCKET;
       freeaddrinfo(result);
    }


    if(IrcSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
       printf("Unable to connect to irc server!");
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<("connection made\n");
    #define NICK "NICK bottester\r\n"
    #define IDENT "USER bottester 0 0 bottester\r\n"
    #define JOIN "JOIN #test\r\n"
    char stringbuffer[256];

    iresult=send(IrcSocket,NICK, strlen(NICK),0);
     if(iresult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(IrcSocket);
       WSACleanup();
       std::cin.get();
       return 1;
    }
    iresult=send(IrcSocket, IDENT, strlen(IDENT),0);
    if(iresult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(IrcSocket);
       WSACleanup();
       std::cin.get();
       return 1;
    }
    std::cout<<"entering ping loop\n";
    char pingnumber[128];
    char pinganswer[17]="PONG :";
    #define PRMSG "PRIVMSG test :TESTBOT IS HERE!\r\n"
    for(;;)
    {
           memset(stringbuffer,0,256);
           recv(IrcSocket,stringbuffer,sizeof(stringbuffer),0);
           for(int j=0;j<strlen(stringbuffer);j++)
           {
                   std::cout<<j<<stringbuffer[j]<<"\n";
           if(stringbuffer[j]=='P' && stringbuffer[j+1]=='I' && stringbuffer[j+2]=='N' && stringbuffer[j+3]=='G')
           {
           memset(pingnumber,0,10);
           std::memcpy(pingnumber, stringbuffer+j+6,10);
           std::memcpy(pinganswer+6,pingnumber,10);
           std::memcpy(pinganswer+16, "\r\n",strlen("\r\n"));
           send(IrcSocket,pinganswer,strlen(pinganswer),0);
           std::cout<< "PINGED<"<<pingnumber<<"\n";
           iresult=send(IrcSocket, JOIN, strlen(JOIN),0);
           std::cout<< "JOINED\n";
           send(IrcSocket, PRMSG, strlen(PRMSG),0);
           }
           }
    }


}
```

Comment: Doesn't the join command start with a `/`?

Comment: when you are using a client yes, when it's just the protocol I  don't believe so.

Comment: You're not processing any responses until the join - something earlier may be failing like the USER or NICK requests.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't waiting for registration to complete before sending JOIN.

Your client is far too simple, really. To kind of get the effect you want, you could put a sleep between the USER/NICK commands and the JOIN command.

The correct non-kludgy solution though is to have a proper send/receive polling loop using poll, select etc, wait for the 001 numeric (the first proper one you receive after registration of the connection) or more correctly either RPL_ENDOFMOTD (376) or ERR_NOMOTD (422). After receiving this line, send your JOIN.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459

Also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also, there's much more you really need to respond to rather than PING to make a functioning client, but this is something for another day. Some servers send a 'security' PING during registration which you must respond to before the server will accept the connection and send the 001 numeric. If you don't respond to this, your connection would never register and eventually ping timeout.